# SELECT DISTINCT UNIQUE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table of products and i need to extract from each idproduct the last 3 unique records IDFornecedor, ie

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNkG5.png)

Result:
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0324.png)

Code:

```
WITH x AS (SELECT        dbo.ItensDocumentos.Referencia, dbo.Documentos.Data, dbo.FacturasFornecedor.IDFornecedor, dbo.ItensDocumentos.IDProduto, dbo.Fornecedores.Nome, dbo.Documentos.BaseIncidenciaIva, 
                         dbo.ItensDocumentos.Quantidade, dbo.ItensDocumentos.TotalIliquido / dbo.ItensDocumentos.Quantidade AS Valor 
FROM                     dbo.ItensDocumentos INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Documentos ON dbo.ItensDocumentos.IDDocumento = dbo.Documentos.IDDocumento INNER JOIN
                         dbo.FacturasFornecedor ON dbo.Documentos.IDDocumento = dbo.FacturasFornecedor.IDDocumento INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Fornecedores ON dbo.FacturasFornecedor.IDFornecedor = dbo.Fornecedores.IDFornecedor
WHERE        (dbo.ItensDocumentos.TotalIliquido / dbo.ItensDocumentos.Quantidade <> 0) AND dbo.Fornecedores.IDFornecedor<> 2 ),
Y AS (SELECT * FROM X), 
Z AS (SELECT IDProduto,Data,Valor,IDFornecedor,Referencia,Nome,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY IDProduto ORDER BY MAX(Data) DESC) AS Seq
           from y
           GROUP BY IDProduto,Data,Valor,IDFornecedor,Referencia,Nome)
SELECT IDProduto,Data,Valor,IDFornecedor,Referencia,Nome,Seq,PorDefeito = 0,PrazoREposicao = 0 from z WHERE Seq <= 3 order by Referencia asc
```

Comment: Please tag your question with the database that you are running: oracle, sql-server, mysql...?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the last three distinct suppliers per product, one option uses aggregation and `row_number()` (if your database supports window functions):

```
select *
from (
    select 
        idProduto, 
        idFornecedor,
        max(data) maxData,
        row_number() over(partition by idProduto order by max(data) desc
    from mytable
    group by idProduto, idFornecedor
) t
where rn <= 3
order by idProduto, idFornecedor, rn desc
```

Comment: but the row with idproduct = 152 and date= 2020-04-30 
appears 2 times and I want only 1 to appear